# How to keep an object moving within a picturebox C#

Tags: c#, game-physics, picturebox, bounds

So i have a the object "player" which is also a picturebox.
It moves left and right using keys. I want it to only be able to move within the picture box (screen) and just stop if it touches the edge and not be able to go outside it.

Here's my attempt

```
        private void Game_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            right = false;

            if (screen.Bounds.IntersectsWith(player.Bounds))
            {
              ???

            }
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            left = false;

        }
    }
```

Could someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, something like this should work.

```
private void Game_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{            
    int leftChange = 0;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)            
        leftChange = 10;     
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)            
        leftChange = -10;

    // check right bound
    if ((player.Right + leftChange) > screen.Right)
        leftChange = (screen.Right - player.Width) - player.Left;
    // check left bound
    if ((player.Left + leftChange) < screen.Left)
        leftChange = screen.Left - player.Left;

    // move the player
    player.Left += leftChange;
}
```